# jquery not(:contains) not working

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to filter the rows that does not contains the specific text.

```
var x = "cotton";

$('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0) td:eq(2) span:not(:contains(' + x + '))').closest("tr");
```

It results in no row but if I use following code to filter rows with specific text then it works fine, so seems like there is something wrong with my implementation of not.

```
$('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0) td:eq(2) span:contains(' + x + ')').closest("tr");
```

Can someone please correct what is wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Update: HTML markup

```
    <table class="SetDWPParameterTabStyle">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="GridHeaderSystemParamter">
                <td style="display: none">
                    Map Id
                </td>
                <td style="display: none; width: 30px;">
                    Type Id
                </td>
                <td style="width: 300px">
                    Material Type
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="display: none">
                    <span id="lblMapId">10</span>
                </td>
                <td style="display: none">
                    <span id="Label3">60</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label1">100% cotton</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="display: none">
                    <span id="lblMapId">20</span>
                </td>
                <td style="display: none">
                    <span id="Label3">70</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="Label1">100% cotton</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
```

Comment: Please provide the matching HTML!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie added the markup...

Comment: All sorted. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `td:eq(2)`, as that only matches the third `td` of *all the matching rows* (not just the third one in each row)!

e.g. problem shown here http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a9mck46m/2/

Use `nth-child(3)` instead:

```
$('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(3) span:contains("' + x + '")').closest("tr");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a9mck46m/1/

`td:nth-child(3)` will match each `td` that is the *3rd child*. Note `nth-child` starts at 1 (to be compatible with the CSS equivalent).

### Update: *"filter is your friend"*:

Once you start to get complex queries, is is much easier to switch to using a `filter` with a function that returns `true` or `false` to include/exclude items.

e.g.

```
var $el = $('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0)').filter(function(){
    return $('td:nth-child(3) span:contains("' + x + '")', this);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a9mck46m/4/

Your additional question, below, asked about combining searches:

The following simply returned a `true` value if both items are found:

```
var x = "cotton";
var y = "Fish";
var $el = $('#divQualCodeFuncPMType > table tbody tr:gt(0)').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:nth-child(3) span:contains("' + x + '")').length && $(this).find('td:nth-child(5) span:contains("' + y + '")').length;
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a9mck46m/5/

Comment: thanks works perfectly. Do you know how this same jquery selector can be modified if I wanna add another filter on say cell 5, so now the selector should get rows which match cell value 3 and 5?

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta: Extra work provide above for combined conditions. `filter()` with a function makes complex filtering easy. Please consider using the little *up arrow* and *tick* buttons to say thank you :)

Comment: almost there. I have updated ur jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mck46m/6/) in the sample row 2nd and 3rd should have been red instead only row 2 is red

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta: Of course it only did row 2. You reversed the logic with `:not`,  but did not reverse the boolean test to  `||` to match. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a9mck46m/7/